# With a storyboard do i have to use Segues?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Might be a stupid question but just want to confirm it:

Lets say i'm using a tableview to present a viewcontroller, while i'm having a storyboard with a segue that pushes the viewcontroller to the navigationController stack.

I know that i need to use the

> prepareForSegue

method.
Does that mean the if ill use methods like

> didSelectRowAtIndexPath

wont get the same results? 
I tried it and my view controller is truly presented BUT the view itself seems to be messed up.

So i just wanted to confirm it.. ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use segues. You can still create view controllers in code completely, or from NIB files, or from the storyboard without a segue (`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`).

Also, any segue you have could just be connected to the view controller itself so it isn't automatically triggered and you execute it in code (`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`).

None of this should have an effect on the layout of the view contents.

Answer (score 0):

As Wain says, you can instantiate/perform segues directly from code.

However if you were configuring the destination view controller via prepareForSegue, that code will never be called if you go the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier route.